# How to forgive people who have wronged you in life?

Tags: dharma, mukti

Forgiving people is essential to get Mukti . How to forgive people who have wronged you in life , who have mistreated you , cheated you etc ?

Comment: you don't have to forgive them if they did something wrong. you are allowed to get revenge (including principal + interest + damages, but not more) if that brings you peace. but if you forgive them, doesn't mean they won't be punished. whenever a person gets mukti, all people who wronged him get his paap, and all the people who benefited him get his punya. the mukta-atma's account balance of paap+punya somehow has to become zero, so Bhagavan ensures it this way.

Comment: @mar Yeah , Many times we are helpless as we have limited power , we can't avenge everytime.

Comment: @mar Could u pls quote the source for the part that a mukta-atma's paap and punya gets distributed in the above manner??

Comment: Thx for asking this question @river I’m struggling w/ this in a huge way  I keep trying to make myself accept things that happened as fate & of course as my own karm-phal. But I’m nowhere near able to accept so much of it ! I struggle hugely w/ anger & sadness over so much stuff  Looking things up here gives me great comfort, so much about past lives stuffs & karm-phal is explained so clearly. But yeah it’s so hard you guys ! & then I wonder how much harder it must be for people who don’t have Hinduism info & understanding available to them like we do. Anyway thx for making this post 

Comment: Also there are some people who are so horrid disgusting persons that I don’t think we should forgive them exactly. Prolly if we can just slowly get to being sorta indifferent to them, slowly try to walk away from them & try to eventually move forward w/ some kinda acceptance. Then that would be ok. There really are many hideous horrible people in Kaliyug who are so evil  I think just moving to the point of being indifferent to them, unemotional to them, & moving forward w/ our own lives, would be good place to be. And I’m not at all able to do it yet, but eventually plz I wish for that 

Comment: @devibhakt - there is a ancient saying in Tamil - theedum nandrum pirar thara varaa - bad and good things do not come from others. meaning we experience our own karma. sometimes it comes in form of others, but it is our own karma only.

Comment: @Rāmachandra - idk which scripture. it is said in all traditional Tamil upanyasa by scholars in many public discourse, so it must have some backing.

Comment: @mar I agree 100% 